# Inititializing and Referencing an Object in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

The question I'm asking is - how do I declare, refer to, instantiate / initialize and set values in an object that is declared as part of another object's header file.

And, any other tips / suggestions are certainly welcomed.

---

I am trying to create a object that is used within another object.  I have tried so many variations and am clearly missing something.

I have a header file for a class (GameDetail) in which I've declared another object (wordMarker) and reference it as follows:

```
@class GameDetail;

// object used to store starting and ending letter for word selection
@interface wordMarker : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) int row;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int col;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int position;
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIButton *button;

@end


@interface GameBoardViewController : UIViewController
{
    AppDelegate *objAppDelegate;

    wordMarker *startingLetter;
    wordMarker *endingLetter;
}
@property GameDetail *gameDetail;

@end
```

And in the class file I have tried variations on the following:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        startingLetter = [wordMarker new];
        endingLetter = [wordMarker new];

    }
    return self;
 }
```

Or a similar call in

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

...
  startingLetter = [[wordMarker alloc] init];
```

And I reference these instances like so:

```
startingLetter.row = letterRow;
startingLetter.col = letterCol;
startingLetter.position = letterNum;
startingLetter.button = validButton;
```

This seemed like the best way to encapsulate, initialize and reference a new object in another but clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks!!

Comment: BTW:  classes should start with a capital letter and be prefixed with a few capital letters....

Comment: *clearly I'm doing something wrong.* and you assume this because...

Comment: You create an object before you need it.  Other than that, it's a judgment call.  (And as bblum says start class names with UpperCase and variables with lowerCase.)

Comment: I'm clearly doing something wrong because the reference code does not actually set the values in the object and / or I get a compilation error: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_wordMarker", referenced from ... linked command failed with exit code 1 (user -v to see invocation).

Comment: @HotLicks - I'm not clear what you're saying.  Are you saying I created the object before I needed it (in which case, XCode wouldn't let me declare it after the other object), or are you saying that I need to create the object before I need in which case, I thought by instantiating it in the init or view methods that I was creating it before I needed it.   Thanks!

Comment: I'm saying that if you try to use it before you create you've got a problem.  Beyond that, when you create it is up to you.  You just need to keep track of it and keep ARC happy.

Comment: Copy the ENTIRE error message into your original question.

Comment: Do you have an `@implementation wordMarker` anywhere? You can't have the interface without the implementation

Comment: @thelaws - that was what was missing.  thank you.  I created an empty implementation wordMarker and it's working.  thanks much.  if you create an answer, i'll vote it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, "I get a compilation error: `"_OBJC_CLASS_$_wordMarker", referenced from ... linked command failed with exit code 1`",

I think you're missing the `@implementation wordMarker`.
You can't declare the interface without the implementation